# Reading an URL when the button click unreported IO compilation error in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, japplet

I'm getting  unreported IOException error Altough i costruct try&catch statement.

This applet tries to invoke a phpscript . So I must read the URL when the button is clicked.

I m new beginner in java. Could you explain what is wrong

Error 44: IO exception must be caught or declared to be thrown

URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();

Error 46: IO exception must be caught or declared to be thrown

myURLConnection.connect();

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class RegisterUser extends Applet{


 //Applet components
TextField panel1 = new TextField(10);
TextField panel2 = new TextField(10);
TextField panel3 = new TextField(10);
Button    save   = new Button("Save");



public void init(){
   //There is two text fields and a button
    add(panel1);
    add(new Label("Name:"));
    addNewLine();
    add(panel2);
    add(new Label("Last:"));
    addNewLine();
    add(save);
    addNewLine();

    // Now tell the button  what it should do when it clicked

   save.addActionListener(new SaveListener());
  }

  class SaveListener implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                    try
          {

          URL myURL = new URL("http://www.myplace.com/save.php?name="+panel1.getText()+"&last_name="+panel2.getText()+"&email="+panel3.getText());

          URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();

          myURLConnection.connect();

          }

          }
          catch (MalformedURLException e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }
    }
      }


      private void addHorizontalLine(Color c)
   {
   // Add a Canvas 10000 pixels wide but only 1 pixel high, which acts as
   // a horizontal line to separate one group of components from the next.
   Canvas line = new Canvas( );
  line.setSize(10000,1);
  line.setBackground(c);
  add(line);
  }


  private void addNewLine( )
 {
   // Add a horizontal line in the background color. The line itself is
   // invisible, but it serves to force the next Component onto a new line.
   addHorizontalLine(getBackground( ));
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry but there are syntax errors in your code. Correct them and update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to catch the checked `IOException` like this

```
catch (IOException exc) {
  // handle exception
}
```

In your `try` `catch` you catch only `MalformedURLException` that is why you get a compilation error.

Comment: Heh-heh.  That first comment of your seems almost comedic in retrospect.  ;)  +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a `}` too much after the `try`-block.

And you also have to catch the `IOException`

Write it like this:

```
      try{
        URL myURL = new URL("http://www.myplace.com/save.php?name="+panel1.getText()+"&last_name="+panel2.getText()+"&email="+panel3.getText());
        URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
        myURLConnection.connect();
      }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }catch (IOException e2){
        System.out.println(e2.getMessage());
      }
```